# McCleary's proof of the multiplicative properties of the Serre Spectral Sequence

Tags: algebraic-topology

In McCleary's book there is a section (5.3) with a proof of the Serre spectral sequence. I am more than confused about the subsection "Multiplicative matters". He cites a paper by Brown which I will refer to here mostly simply because McCleary's version of the proof does not seem well thought out (he uses local coefficients without basepoint, but he does not seem to take this into account correctly, see the end of the post). It all comes to showing the formula 5.29. However, the cochain $C_{q'}(E) \to \mathbb{Z}, U \mapsto f(\pi S)(U')$ (where $S$ is some fixed simplex in $E$) does not make sense to me, because it is only well-defined if $U'$ is completely contained in the fiber over the basepoint. We can force it to be a cochain on $E$ by extending it arbitrarily, but then $D(f, f')(T)$ is still only well-defined for $T \in F_{p+p'}$. The statement in 5.29. is about *all* simplices $T$ however. The good thing is that it might be sufficient to define it *up to* some filtration degree, but I simply don't see how the details can work out. I could  theoretically provide some more calculations but I imagine anyone attempting to prove the lemma will run into my problems.

I wonder how a standard reference like that can fail at providing a clear proof. (By the way, here is another thing: McCleary keeps mentioning the assumption that the fiber $F$ be connected, but this assumption makes no appearance in the proof section 5.3 at all. Why does he have it, then?)

*See:
McCleary: "A user's guide to Spectral Sequences", E. H. Brown: "The Serre spectral sequence theorem for continuous and ordinary cohomology"*

*Appendix:* I imagine that in order to develop the product structure in McCleary's framework one has to define the cup-product on $C^\bullet(B; C^\bullet(F_b))  = \text{Hom}(C_\bullet(B; C_\bullet(F_b)),\mathbb{Z})$ as follows: for $f \in C^p(B; C^q(F_b)), f' \in C^{p'}(B; C^{q'}(F_b))$ define $f \smile f' \in C^{p+p'}(B; C^{q+q'}(F_b))$ by

$$ (f \smile f')(V) = f(V(0, \dots, p)) \smile \Phi^\ast(f'(V(p, \dots, p+p'))) $$
on $V: \Delta^{p+p'} \to B$, where $\smile$ denotes ordinary cup product in the fiber over $V(v_0)$ and $\Phi: F_{V(v_o)} \to F_{V(v_p)}$ is associated the the straight path connecting $V(v_0)$ and $V(v_p)$. I would be interested to know if someone has thought this through.